# Is this a functional method for proving continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, proof-writing, proof-theory

In the context of metric spaces when trying to prove the continuity of a function is the result we seek

$f(x)-f(y) \le d(x,y)$

i.e. does this result prove that the function is continuous ?

Comment: If you have absolute values then yes, since the distance function itself is always continuous. As written no.

Comment: @Ian so the result we seek is always $|f(x)-f(y)| \le d(x,y)$ ?

Comment: It is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: By the way, @Ian, absolute value seems actually unnecessary in view of symmetry?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your property, with the absolute value, is Lipschitz-1 continuity, which is stronger than continuity. (E.g., the functions $x^2$ or $e^x$ are very continuous but don't satisfy this.)

Continuity at a point $y$ means for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$.

Often more intuitive is: if $x_n\to y$, then $f(x_n)\to f(y)$.

Comment: so what is the minimum result I need, to show that a function is continuous ?

Comment: added the definition and sequential characterization.